# include .so in Android Studio with Build:Gradle:2.1.0

Tags: android-studio, shared-libraries, build.gradle, ndk-build

I know there are many similar questions but I simply don't understand it.

I have managed to integrate ndk-build within build.gradle but it seems I cant include the .so in my .apk. Here is my build.gralde:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "masterproject.student_at_university_kiel.knauf.torsten"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        // for preventing (cheating) gradle-build to overwrite Android.mk with auto-generated Android.mk (NdkCompile task)
        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs/' //integrate your libs from libs instead of jniLibs
        }

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }

        task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
            def ndkDir = "/home/expert/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle"
            workingDir "src/main/jni"
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build"
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    }
```

and this leads to the following directory structure:

```
|--app:
|--|--src:
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--java
|--|--|--libs
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
```

At runtime of my App I get an `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:` when calling a native function...

I have found many things like:

```
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}
```

But I don't understand that and it feels unnecessary to me to create .jar archives for the native code. Or have I missed something completely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, the `task nativeLibsToJar` does the trick, but it does. Maybe there will be some answer on my new asked question [magic of nativeLibsToJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447811/what-is-the-magic-of-nativelibstojar)

Here's my build.gradle file, which works fine. Maybe someone will find it usefull :)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "masterproject.student_at_university_kiel.knauf.torsten"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // for preventing (cheating) gradle-build to overwrite Android.mk with auto-generated Android.mk (default NdkCompile task)
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs/' //integrate your libs from libs instead of jniLibs
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'compile native code') {
        def ndkDir = "/home/expert/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle"
        workingDir "src/main/jni"
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build"
    }

    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
        destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
        baseName 'native-libs'
        extension 'jar'
        from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
        into 'lib/'
    }
    nativeLibsToJar.dependsOn {
        ndkBuild  // comment that, when you don't want to rerun ndk-build script
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```